# Alternative GUI for Open Source Job Scheduler

Tags: job-scheduler

Are there some alternative open source GUI developed to improve the management of jobs and job chains in [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is there aren't alternative GUIs for Job Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are definitely looking for another tool than JobScheduler, you can look at RunDeck:

http://rundeck.org/

Answer (score -2):

Open Source JobScheduler offers GUI editors on their website. You can configure those editors to connect to your JobScheduler server via FTP as hot folder and have access to all your jobs in a GUI. You can create, edit, delete jobs from there.

It requires an installation and is Java based.

https://kb.sos-berlin.com/display/PKB/How+to+use+JOE+to+configure+jobs+and+orders+on+remote+computers